# Get object from array on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Json gives me the tag "image" as array or object, and I just want a new array that contains:

- The frist object of the array when "image" is an array( **"image": [..**).
- The object when "image" is an object( **"image": {..**).

¿Is it possible on javascript?

This is a sample of my json

```
    {
    "results": {
"collection1": [
  {
    "date": [
      {
        "href": "",
        "text": "Feb"
      },
      {
        "href": "",
        "text": "25"
      },
      {
        "href": "",
        "text": "2015"
      }
    ],
    "image": {
      "alt": "",
      "src": "http://img.rlsbb.com/images/uAJisteKNw.jpg",
      "text": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "date": [
      {
        "href": "",
        "text": "Feb"
      },
      {
        "href": "",
        "text": "18"
      },
      {
        "href": "",
        "text": "2015"
      }
    ],
    "image": [
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "http://img.rlsbb.com/images/uAJosteUNw.jpg",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-VdJQw_nXO0k/UoAwpBL8yjI/AAAAAAAAABU/H_fKtjG8H5Y/s1600/Online.jpg",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  }}
```

Comment: What's the problem, did you try it?

Comment: It is not advisable to have an inconsistently typed key value. You should either have 1 image object all the time. Or have an array of images (preferably named "images") all the time.